# Google analytics C# project - authentication fails

Tags: c#, google-analytics

I am using this simple server-side code to create a google authentication token that to be used on the client side for embedding a view

```
    private void GenarateGAToken()
    {
        GoogleCredential credential;
        string keyFilePath = Server.MapPath("") + MYKEYFILENAME;
        using (Stream stream = new FileStream(keyFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream);
        }
        string[] scopes = new string[] { AnalyticsService.Scope.Analytics };             credential = credential.CreateScoped(scopes);

        try
        {
            bearer = ((ITokenAccess)credential).GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync().Result;
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            throw ex.InnerException;
        }
    }
```

I use the token on the page to authorise the API

```
gapi.analytics.ready(function() {
    gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
    'serverAuth': {
        'access_token': '{{ <%=bearer%> }}'
    }
    });
```

But I get back error 401 "Invalide Credentials":

```
{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"authError","message":"Invalid Credentials","locationType":"header","location":"Authorization"}],"code":401,"message":"Invalid Credentials"}}
```

Tested the token value on https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token= 
And it looks valid

The Google account seems to be set correctly with a service account with all required permissions

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Well, found the stupid copy-paste problem
I copied and pasted this:

```
gapi.analytics.ready(function() {
    gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
    'serverAuth': {
        'access_token': '{{ <%=bearer%> }}'
    }
    });
```

The curly brackets are the problem, they are just placeholder and should be removed, so this works:

```
gapi.analytics.ready(function() {
    gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
    'serverAuth': {
        'access_token': '<%=bearer%>'
    }
    });
```